# Is my multi-switch lighting circuit plan valid?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Is this wiring valid?  If not, please explain how it could be corrected?
I replaced the original diagram with this one based on corrections and clarifications recommended in the comments.
[image]

Comment: Did you mean for the color of the wire nuts to have any significance?

Comment: The junction to the LED lights needs to be in a Junction box, not just wirenutted loose in the wall/ceiling someplace. Which is what the diagram implies...

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri The diagram system seems to be smart enough to realize when a yellow nut will work (2x 14 gauge) and when you probably want a larger red nut (3 or more 14 gauge). The green wire nuts are uncommon, but probably for clarity in the diagram

Comment: @Machavity: Yes, yellow for two wires and red for three wires, just as many manufacturers color them -- but this scheme is not applied in the right half of the diagram, where red is used for two wires. I remarked on this minor flaw in an otherwise exemplary diagram in case the author might care about such things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work and seems to follow best practice.

Be sure to check that the breaker protecting this circuit is 15 Amps. You cannot use 14 gauge wire on a 20 Amp circuit.

Note that the octagon ceiling box for the first light is grounded. If the switch boxes are metal and the wiring is not in metal conduit then the switch boxes should be grounded too.

For anyone else reading this later, Ken's diagram doesn't show it but the LED fixtures must be connected in parallel. And grounded.

Comment: The coloring of the wire nuts is inconsistent.  I will do as mentioned in earlier comments. The LED lights are actually connected inside the box attached to the LED lights. The diagram does not really show that.  Thanks for everyones suggestions and critiques.